WireMock.Net 1.6.8 ovverides Ihttpfactory.CreateClient()?
Note that I am a novice when it comes to programming.
I have an issue where I want to create an integration test for my service.
The service does several external API-calls. Which is why I wanted to use WireMock to mock the responses.
Since I want to test the whole stack from controller and pass all the API-calls, I created an httpclient via my WebApplicationFactory. Reason for this is that I do not want to mock a response for the first API-call, only the external API-calls.
It works fine from here, but!
When I install the WireMock. the first httpclient fails with status 500. Eventhough I explicitly tells the WireMock only to listen to a specific URL which is not used by my factory httpclient. This also is true if I remove all codes related to WireMock.
So it feels like the nugget package itself disrupts the standard httpclient?
Any suggestions on why this happends?
